# HTML/JSP/Servlet problems on signin page

Tags: java, html, jsp

I tried to create a personal website with a login page. First you have to create a account and that information will be stored in my computer in a text file. Everything goes well until I try to login. 
I wrote a code to check if the users write their account information is right or wrong in order to login. But every time it always says `User or password is not correct` even with the right account. Here's my code so far

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String user = request.getParameter("u1");
String pass = request.getParameter("u2");
HttpSession session = request.getSession();


try {
     FileReader inputFile = new FileReader("D:/data.txt");
     BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);
     String a;
     String b;

    while ((a = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (a.equals(user)) {
            b = bufferReader.readLine();
            if (b.equals(pass)) {
                session.setAttribute("login", user);
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

            } else {
                session.setAttribute("login failed", "Your username or password is incorrect");
                response.sendRedirect("signinfailed.jsp");
                break;
            }
        }  else {
            session.setAttribute("login failed", "Your username or password is incorrect");
            response.sendRedirect("signinfailed.jsp");
            break;
        }
    }
    bufferReader.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Exception");
}
finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't it catch any exceptions? Have you checked your log?

I see one problem right of the bat:

```
FileReader inputFile = new FileReader("D:/data.txt");
```

You're using a Windows filesystem - paths in Windows need to use `\` not `/`. Try changing your path to:

```
FileReader inputFile = new FileReader("D:\\data.txt");
```

**Edit for checking the `data.txt`** with username and password:

Change your `data.txt` to a better readable structure, for example this is how you can check multiple users in a `[user]:[password]` scheme:

Data.txt

> john:pwd123
>
> steve:WTFomgBBQ1
>
> bob:bob

and so on.. Then you can use:

```
public boolean checkLogin(String userName, String password) throws IOException {
    
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
        new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\data.txt"));
    
    String line;
    String[] currentPair;
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        currentPair = line.split(":");
        if(currentPair[0].equals(userName) && currentPair[1].equals(password))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So everything you really need after the submitting of the form is to check:

```
String login = request.getParameter("login");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
if(checkLogin(login, password))
{
    response.sendRedirect(SUCCESS_URL);
}
else
{
    response.sendRedirect(BAD_PASS);
}
// SUCCESS_URL and BAD_PASS are URLs for your redirect
```

Comment: i think it is not a problem, my data.txt seem to run (store) it normally when i try creating an account

Comment: Ok, so can you post your data.txt? Change the passwords to something else.. Do you have only one user in your data.txt?

Comment: Here is my content in data.txt:

Comment: Here is my data.txt, the first 2 rows is uname and password

da
12345
da
r1
----------------------
trivip
hahaha
minhtri0106@yahoo.com
r1
----------------------
trai
efaf
akdsfhj
r1
----------------------
dantemanh
12345
DM@gmail.com
r2
----------------------
trivip93
hihihi
minhtri0106@yahoo.com
r1
----------------------



r2
----------------------



r2
----------------------
johnnguyen
kakaka
nmtri.itc@gmail.com
r1
----------------------



r2
----------------------
hohoho
hahaha
kakaka@yahoo.com
r2
----------------------

Comment: No problem, just tell me afterwards if it fixed it for you, I'll try to help further if not. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the information in the file? If the user is not written in the first line and the password on the second line it will fail.

You can add in the line for the second else the value of `a`. You can add `session.setAttribute ("login failed", "Your username or password is incorrect" + a)`, and you can see what is being read in the file.

Comment: thank you for answering, the username and pasword are in the right order